# How can I link to the debug QT libraries without being the debug config with cmake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Without explicitly stating it, Qt seems to link the debug version of it's libraries when the target is debug. So in the Debug config it will link "C:\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2015\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib" and in the Release version it will link "C:\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2015\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib". I have a third config, named ToolsDebug and I want to link to the debug version of Qt. I know there is a way to link libraries with target_link_libraries but when explicitly telling it to link the Qt5Widgetsd.lib version it will link both

This is my minimal example of how I am creating the application. With having just this it will link the debug version of the libraries in debug

```
project(AllMyCode CXX)
set(Qt5_DIR "C:\\Qt\\5.11.2\\msvc2015\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS
            Core
            Widgets
            Gui)
            
file(GLOB_RECURSE _source_list *.cpp* *.h*)
add_executable(ExampleApp ${_source_list})
```

Comment: [`set_target_properties(Qt5::Widgets PROPERTIES MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_TOOLSDEBUG Debug)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) may work, but I never tested this.

Comment: @fabian Unfortunately that didn't set the library to use as the debug variant. There were no errors and I know the make file was ran

Comment: Have you tried the [DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS.html) global property:

`set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS TestDebug)`

As documented the property should be set early

> This property must be set at the top level of the project and before the first target_link_libraries() command invocation.

Comment: @mydisplayname I tried both the APPEND and the setting by using PROPERTY, but that did not seem to pick it up

Comment: "when explicitly telling it to link the Qt5Widgetsd.lib version it will link both" - Probably, some other library, which is linked to your executable, links with Release version of QT. Please, show your code (in form of [mcve]).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added an example

Comment: @judeclarke You may try asking this on the cmake-users mailing list as well.

Comment: Ok, so it is `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` which (among other things) automatically links your application with QT libraries... It is interesting which way it uses for that linkage.